# Share ASP.Net MVC Identiity cookie accross subdomains

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, subdomain

I have single application hosted at multiple subdomains as
1- `www.mydomain.ae`
2- `student.mydomain.ae`
3- `teacher.mydomain.ae`

in `Startup.Auth.cs` file I have added the following line

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
  {
     AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
     LoginPath = new PathString("/en/Account/Login"),

     CookieDomain = ".mydomain.ae",  /****ADDED THIS LINE***/

     Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
     {
       OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
       validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
       regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
     }
});
```

it is working on my local environment in when I hit `CTRL+F5` but after publishing and uploading on live server it is not working

*EDIT: additional things*
I also noticed logout is redirecting to homepage but not clearing cookie. once logged-in can not logout

Comment: have you set the machine key on web.config?

Comment: No, but i have `<httpCookies domain=".mydomain.ae"/>` in web.config too

Comment: the logout part happened because you didn't set the LogoutPath in the CookieAuthenticationOptions

Comment: you can use database for storing cookie as session state https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/25c78a/load-balancing-session-state-configuration/